# Creating a powered usb for raspberry pi

Tags: power-supply, usb, raspberry-pi

I need to make a usb which is powered by an external 5v power supply, but still connect the device being powered to the raspberry pi.
To do this I've attached the 2 data pins directly to the raspberry pi, the positive pin to the external power supply, and the ground pin is split to the usb on the raspberry pi and the ground of my external power source. Is this a valid circuit?
Thanks

Edit: To clear things up, I have a female usb breakout, which my device will be plugged into instead of the raspberry pi's usb port. I have then connected the data lines of said female usb port to the port on raspberry pi, the positive is connected to an external power supply, and the ground is split between the external power and the ground on the usb of the pi.

Comment: You should spend some time studying the idea of the "self-powered USB device".  Formally, at lest the device is supposed to *watch* the host's VBus even if it doesn't *run off of it*.

Comment: @jsotola Ive edited the post, hopefully it makes more sence